# How to create Android layout ratingbar with multiline text view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have design with rating bar and multiline textview

Anyone help how to create android layout xml file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this for rating-bar also multiline text view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">
    <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/> 
    <TextView
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/progressBar"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create RatingBar using xml below

```
 <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
        android:rating="2.0" />
```

now for Multiline TextView used this;

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
```

set property `android:inputType = "textMultiLine"` it will allow multiline text.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_user_interface_layouts.htm) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) also

**Detail in Brief**

you can use LinearLayout/RelativeLayout/FrameLayout/TableLayout to display different controls.

**LinearLayout** - As name suggest you will put control in Linear Way (Horizontal/Vertical)

// you can set control vertically or horizontally

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="play"
   />
```

**RelativeLayout** - add control relative to other

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#bbbbff">

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/playButton"/> rating bar is in bottom in parent and to left of your button

    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="play"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" // button will be right side in parent view
        android:id="@+id/playButton"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

please go through link for more details. hope this will help.